# How to get rid of from intertrigo by using home remedies?

Tags: infection, home-remedies, itching, groin

For someone suffering from Intertrigo skin infection in their groin area. Is there any home remedy to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

[Intertrigo](http://www.m.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/guide/intertrigo-symptoms-causes-treatment-risk_factors_): For prevention and stopping furthering of symptoms

> Shower and dry off thoroughly each day. Keep your skin as dry and cool
>   as you can. Avoid wearing tight shoes or clothing. Wear a bra with
>   good support. If the areas between the toes are affected, consider
>   wearing open-toed shoes. For infants with diaper rash, change diapers
>   more frequently. If you are overweight, do what you can to lose
>   weight.

[Medscape](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1087691-treatment#d9)

> Take steps to eliminate friction, heat, and maceration by keeping
>   folds cool and dry. These steps can be accomplished by using air
>   conditioning and absorbent powders, wearing moisture-wicking polyester
>   underwear and socks (eg, Orlon) and by exposing skin folds to the air.
>   Compresses with Burow solution 1:40, dilute vinegar, or wet tea bags
>   often are effective, especially if followed by fanning or cool
>   blow-drying.

The above is treatmebt for Intertrigo. A doctor's visit is recomended however due to some cases needing steroids or other topicals and the risk for infection.

Comment: Can i use apple cider vinegar for this?